# position property trouble with slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I am trying to display a slideshow at the top of my homepage which requires using position:relative & position:absolute. The slideshow works fine, but I notice that the contents below it, ex. the text that should be below the slideshow and the buttons that should also be below the slideshow is coming up and overlapping over the slideshow. How can I properly position the elements below the slideshow so that they are not overlapping with different screen sizes? I am new to all this so I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Here is my code:

```js
const slideshowImages = document.querySelectorAll(".hero .mySlides");

         const nextImageDelay = 5000; 
         let currentImageCounter= 0;

         slideshowImages[currentImageCounter].style.opacity = 1;
         setInterval(nextImage, nextImageDelay);

         function nextImage(){
             //slideshowImages[currentImageCounter].style.opacity = 0;
             slideshowImages[currentImageCounter].style.zIndex = -2;
             const tempCounter = currentImageCounter;
             setTimeout(() => {
                 slideshowImages[tempCounter].style.opacity = 0;
             }, 1000);
             currentImageCounter = (currentImageCounter + 1) % slideshowImages.length;
             slideshowImages[currentImageCounter].style.opacity = 1;
             slideshowImages[currentImageCounter].style.zIndex = -1;
           }
```

```css
.hero {
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
           justify-content: center;
           align-items: center;
           position: relative;
           height: 10vh;
          }

        .mySlides {
           position: absolute;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
           width: 100%;
           object-fit: cover;
           z-index: -1;
           opacity: 0;
           transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
          }

        .hero-text {
           width: 100%;
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
           align-items: center;
           position: absolute;
           height: 15vh;
           top:350px;
         }
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

the buttons do not have position properties.

Comment: Can't see your slideshow running

Comment: It would be helpful if u  add a https://codepen.io/ example.

Comment: Here's my codepen with a snippet of my code. the slideshow looks okay with certain screen sizes... but not all.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. https://codepen.io/Tomi21/pen/LYNWQGQ